# Simple Angular component throwing many errors

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm totally new to Angular 2 (MEAN stack). I started just 1 hour ago.

I'm following the official tutorial for newbies (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt1.html)

I have this `app.component.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export class Hero {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

hero: Hero = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Windstorm'
};

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1>{{title}}</h1> <h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2>'
})

export class AppComponent  { 
    title = 'Tour of Heroes';
}
```

Just as the tutorial says it must be done. Now, the console throw me a lot of errors.

I don't have any idea about what could be the issue.

[image: Angular error]

---

**Edit 1:**

Trying to downgrade Zone.JS like this `npm i --save zone.js@0.7.2` (previously 0.7.5) just broke something. Now `npm start` throw this error:

[image: Zone.JS error]

---

**Edit 2:**

I modified the start object in `package.json` to this:

`"start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",`

Seems to work properly (now the localhost is working).

The console keeps showing the errors like the above image.

Comment: simple google search on the error brought up this: https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/427 try some of the things mentioned there

Comment: Please check my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is slightly incorrect.  the `hero` instance is in the wrong location.

In order to be accessible to other parts of the app (and to the template), the instance needs to be inside the `export`.  The error you are getting is alerting you to the fact that you are trying to create a template binding with an instance that isn't exported.

The correct code looks like the following:

```
...
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1>{{title}}</h1> <h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2>'
})

export class AppComponent  { 
    title = 'Tour of Heroes';
    hero: Hero = {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Windstorm'
    };
}
```

Comment: Now it's working, thanks for explaining! Being curious I tried doing something like this: `@Component({ selector: 'title', template: '123'})` so the document title should be changed to "123", is not working, maybe because Angular can't modify outside the `body`?

Comment: because `<title></title>` is outside the `<body>` tag, it's not part of the angular lifecycle;  however, angular provides a `Title` service to make a browser platform call.  see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/set-document-title.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<h2>{{hero.name}}
```

is invalid because the component class doesn't have a `hero` field and the component instance is the scope of bindings in the view